# How to change icon to a "plus" or "minus" depending on table cell value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am new to react, what I am trying to do is to change the icon symbol from a "plus" to a "minus" or vice versa when the value in a certain cell changes that is, when the cell has a positive value the symbol next to it should be a "plus" symbol and a negative value in the cell change the symbol to a "minus"

Here is a code sample of what I am trying to do

Is this the right approach ?

I am using Semantic-UI for the symbols

````
<Table >
      <Table.Body>
              <Table.Row>
                  <p>Total Assets/Liabilities:</p>
                      <td>12</td>
                        <td "tabledatavalue" >= 0 
                ? <Icon name="plus"></Icon> : 
                  <Icon name="minus"></Icon> 
             </td></Table.Row> 
       </Table.Body>
</Table>```
````

Answer (score 3):

You can read about conditional rendering in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

In your case you can do this:

```
    <td>
      {this.state.cellValue}
      {this.state.cellValue >= 0 ? (
        <Icon name="plus"></Icon>
      ) : (
        <Icon name="minus"></Icon>
        )}
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize your code to use a conditional check within the `name` props in your `<Icon />` instead of declaring two `<Icon />` with different name. This will make your codes easier to maintain.

```
<Table>
  <Table.Body>
    <Table.Row>
      <p>Total Assets/Liabilities:</p>
      <td>
        {cellValue}
        <Icon name={cellValue >= 0 ? "plus" : "minus"} />
      </td>
    </Table.Row>
  </Table.Body>
</Table>
```